# Contourplot in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, contour

[image]

I want to draw a plot like attached here. I can draw the grid lines and contour lines separately but I am unable to draw the contour lines as well as grid points together. Here is a sample script which doesn't work as desired:

```
set size square
set border 15 lw 2
set multiplot
set contour
set dgrid3d
set view 0,0,1 
unset surface
unset key
unset ztics
set cntrparam levels 100
sp './ratio.dat' u 1:2:3 w l title 'contour'
unset multiplot
```

Please give me some suggestions. Please note that I want to draw in gnuplot.

My data file is:

```
3.24 4.78       -.35290652E+02
3.24 4.80       -.35294651E+02
3.24 4.82       -.35296568E+02
3.24 4.84       -.35296243E+02
3.24 4.86       -.35293913E+02
3.26 4.78       -.35297184E+02
3.26 4.80       -.35300060E+02
3.26 4.82       -.35300636E+02
3.26 4.84       -.35299307E+02
3.26 4.86       -.35296067E+02
3.28 4.78       -.35301762E+02
3.28 4.80       -.35303628E+02
3.28 4.82       -.35303411E+02
3.28 4.84       -.35301143E+02
3.28 4.86       -.35296928E+02
3.30 4.78       -.35305133E+02
3.30 4.80       -.35305871E+02
3.30 4.82       -.35304504E+02
3.30 4.84       -.35301162E+02
3.30 4.86       -.35296027E+02
3.32 4.78       -.35306428E+02
3.32 4.80       -.35306195E+02
3.32 4.82       -.35303920E+02
3.32 4.84       -.35299762E+02
3.32 4.86       -.35293913E+02
3.34 4.70       -.35293485E+02
3.34 4.72       -.35299524E+02
3.34 4.74       -.35303637E+02
3.34 4.76       -.35305766E+02
3.36 4.70       -.35295404E+02
3.36 4.72       -.35300430E+02
3.36 4.74       -.35303365E+02
3.36 4.76       -.35304614E+02
3.38 4.70       -.35295225E+02
3.38 4.72       -.35299351E+02
3.38 4.74       -.35301673E+02
3.38 4.76       -.35302240E+02
3.40 4.70       -.35293798E+02
3.40 4.72       -.35297246E+02
3.40 4.74       -.35298743E+02
3.40 4.76       -.35298443E+02
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. Something like `set contours base; splot 'data.txt', 'data.txt' nocontours` should work fine.

Comment: I have tried this:

gnuplot> set output 'tanmoy.eps'
gnuplot> set key spacing 1.5
gnuplot> set size square
gnuplot> set border 15 lw 2
gnuplot> set multiplot
multiplot> set contour
multiplot> set dgrid3d
multiplot> set view 0,0,1
multiplot> unset surface
multiplot> unset key
multiplot> unset ztics
multiplot> set cntrparam levels 100
multiplot> sp './ratio.dat' u 1:2:3 w l title 'contour'
multiplot> unset multiplot
gnuplot> set contour base
gnuplot> splot './ratio.dat', './ratio.dat' nocontours
 not working like what I want